# Evaluating this generalized integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$I(a)=\int_0^1 \left({\frac{x^a-1}{\log_ex}} \right)^n \, dx$$

My attempts include using Binomial expansion to $(x^a-1)^n$ = $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}x^{(n-k)a}$

$$I(a)= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}\int_0^1 {\frac{x^{(n-k)a}}{(\log_ex)^n}} \, dx$$

It would be great to learn how to proceed further with this integral.

Comment: Not like I know how to solve the problem, but have you tried taking the partial derivative, with respect to $a$, of the integrand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $x = e^{-t}$ and performing integration by parts $n-1$ times, we get

\begin{align*}
I(a)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1 - e^{-at}}{t}\right)^n e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}t^{n-1}} (1 - e^{-at})^n e^{-t} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{IbP}
\end{align*}

To evaluate the last integral, we write

$$ \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}t^{n-1}} (1 - e^{-at})^n e^{-t} \right) = - P_n(e^{-t}) \tag{1} $$

for the function $P_n(x)$ defined by

$$ P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} (ak+1)^{n-1} x^{ak+1}. $$

Since the left-hand side of $\text{(1)}$ vanishes at $t = 0$, we have $P_n(1) = 0$. Then by using the Frullani-type identity

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-at}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t = \log a, $$

it follows that

\begin{align*}
I(a)
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{P_n(1)e^{-t} - P_n(e^{-t})}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} (ak+1)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-(ak+1)t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} (ak+1)^{n-1} \log(ak + 1).
\end{align*}

Just for fun, I also included a numerical simulation:

[image: numerical simulation]

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^ax^tdt=\frac{x^a-1}{\log x}$ therefore
$$I_n(a)=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^a....\int_0^ax^{t_1+\cdots+t_n}dt_1\ldots dt_n\right)dx=\int_0^a....\int_0^a\frac{dt_1\ldots dt_n}{1+t_1+\ldots+t_n}$$ and look for an induction formula after computing $I_n$ for $n=0,\ldots 4.$